# How to make displacement working on imported objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement

If I use a displacement (shader) with geometry created in Blender (Cubes, Planes etc) it's working perfectly. However, when using displacement on imported geometry (shader) it's not working at all.

Is there any solution to this?

[image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/YXeEBjjq

Comment: hi jachym, thanks for your reply. I know that I need Adaptive Subdivison, but also with that turned on, it's not working the way it should be. Maybe you could be more precise about that 'many other issues'?

Comment: The imported meshes are cildren of empties with very low scale.

Comment: @FFeller would you know how to apply scale for parented objects? Without clearing the parent relationship?

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍ ᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ Applying transforms doesn't affect the parent relationship. I don't think the relation was an aspect. Anyway, you gave a precise answer.

Comment: @FFeller Well, scale of parented objects cannot be applied directly it seems. I needed to remove the parent first. Maybe I'm doing something wrong :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things for this to work

**Proper UV maps** (main reason)
- your imported objects have broken or even *missing* UV maps, so the displacement doesn't work
- to solve this, select all faces of the mesh and go *UV > Smart UV Project*

**Connect Displacement texture**
- your node setup is very... unusual :)
- you need to connect your Displacement Texture directly into the Displacement node

**Apply scale**
- some of your objects have very small scale (0.01) which also affects final displacement
- apply the scale through *Object > Apply > Scale*  so it 1.

*Apply scale to parented objects*
- some object's are parented - you need to clear the parent before applying scale
- select parented object and go <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Clear and Keep Transformation*

---

*How to create a simple UV map*.
*This is just a quick and dirty way. Learn to unwrap objects manually*

[image]

*How to connect Displacement texture*

[image]

*How to clear parent and apply scale*
*Do this for all imported objects, just to be sure*

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, 'apply scale' was the step i wasn't aware of...

Comment: Happy to help :). You can now mark the answer as accepted **✓**, so others can easily find it.